# Oracle APEX 20.1 - Customize Field Help / Tooltips

Tags: tooltip, field, apex

I see **Help Text** and **Inline Help Text** properties for columns in APEX 20.1, but I don't see any options for customizing how the field help is displayed.  Does that ability exist?

For example, the Inline Help Text displays below the field.  Is there a way to specify that:

- It should display to the right of the field?
- It should display as a tool tip, when the cursor enters the field?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the requirement is to specify some text to the right of the field then use **Post Text** property instead of **Inline Help Text** property.
2. To show a tooltip paste the below code in the **Function and Global Variables** section

   ```
   $('#MY_PAGE_ITEM').attr('title', 'My Tooltip Text');
   ```

**Note:**

- Replace **MY_PAGE_ITEM** with your Page Item name.
- Replace **My Tooltip Text** with the required text.